# Error while executing make command

Tags: make

I created simple kernel module while executing make command error encountered.

[image]

```
zeeshan@zeeshan-Y11C:~/modules$ make

make -C/lib/modules/5.0.0-31-generic/build/ M=/home/zeeshan/modules modules

make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-31-generic'

arch/x86/Makefile:146: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support

./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: gcc: command not found
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 27: gcc: command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
  CC [M]  /home/zeeshan/modules/simple.o

/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
scripts/Makefile.build:291: recipe for target '/home/zeeshan/modules/simple.o' failed

make[2]: *** [/home/zeeshan/modules/simple.o] Error 127
Makefile:1608: recipe for target '_module_/home/zeeshan/modules' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/zeeshan/modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.0-31-generic'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Can you post the error as text, instead of, presumably, a link to an image of a window of a program with that text.

Comment: It looks like you haven't installed `build-essential` in order to compile code  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/build-essential) but pictures of text are harder to read than text itself...

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a C compiler installed. Install the package `build-essential`, that will install a C compiler and some other thing you usually need to build programs written in C.